# Creating classes via loops and variables

Tags: loops, less

I have groups which all have the same properties but different values. I was wondering if there is a quick way of looping through my variables to create classes?

```
@groups : 3

@group1 : #59344F
@group2 : #8BBF9F
@group3 : #857E7B


.group-loop(@i) when (@i > 0){
    .group-@{i}-colors{
        color: @group@{i}
     }
}

.group-loop(@groups);
```

The error I get is : no viable alternative at input 'color' in ruleset

Comment: You're basically trying to emulate Array/List? **Don't**: Less has native arrays/lists.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use the `extract` function in order to get the value of the array at the specific index.

Here is the doc: http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract

So you'd have to update your code to something like this:

```
@colorsArr : #59344F, #8BBF9F, #857E7B;


.group-loop(@colors, @index) when (@index > 0){
    .group-@{index}-colors{
        color: extract(@colors, @index)
     }

    .group-loop(@colorsArr, (@index - 1))
}

.group-loop(@colorsArr, length(@colorsArr));
```

I made colors an array or list. This is a recursive loop, which a pretty good way of looping this. Basically the `.group-loop` at the bottom kicks off the loop, and you can see we are calling the function again before the end of the loop and decrementing the index down in order to keep the `when` check working.